# SQL - get records within date range, incl. same day records

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

I am struggling with something (hopefully) simple here. I have an online logbook that I review on a daily basis. Each day has a number of logcases that I must review, hence I built a simple date-filter to screen each day's logcases on the main page.

Now, when loading the main page for the first time (meaning, with the default filter conditions), I want the page to show all logcases of the most recent DAY on file. So if for example today is the 10th of the month and the most recent case was submitted on the 8th, then I want to query ALL cases from the 8th.

If on the other hand somebody has already filed a logfile for the 10th, then I want to display all records from the 10th.

The problem here now is that the query does accurately identify the date if the last record, but the cutoff TIME seems to be midnight or 00:01, meaning it will not display any logfiles that were submitted on that day AFTER one minute past midnight! So if I want to see today's cases, I will only see those submitted between 00:00 to 00:01, making the whole filter useless.

Query

```
$sql = "SELECT *
FROM qci_dmlog_data
WHERE Incident_Date IN (
    SELECT MAX( Incident_Date )
    FROM qci_dmlog_data
    WHERE Holidex = '".$_SESSION['Holidex']."'
)
GROUP BY LogID ORDER BY Date DESC";
```

To sum it up, how can I filter records of the most recent DAY without caring about what TIME they were submitted?

Thanks!

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Without the type of your date-fields this is hard to tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look for the date part of incident date to get all the records from the most recent date.

```
SELECT *
FROM qci_dmlog_data
WHERE DATE(Incident_Date) IN (
    SELECT MAX(DATE(Incident_Date))
    FROM qci_dmlog_data
    WHERE Holidex = '".$_SESSION['Holidex']."'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to correlated the subquery on `Holidex` in addition to only using the `date` portion of the "date":

```
SELECT d.*
FROM qci_dmlog_data d
WHERE d.Holidex = '".$_SESSION['Holidex']."' AND
      DATE(d.Incident_Date) = (SELECT MAX(DATE(d2.Incident_Date))
                               FROM qci_dmlog_data d2
                               WHERE d2.Holidex = d.Holidex
                              );
```

This assumes that "most recent date" is per `Holidex`.

Comment: thanks, this works as well but `Holidex` is not related to the `date` operation I am doing here. Holidex is merely a unique user identifier I use to distinguish user submissions. Still, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Armitage2k . . . In that case, VKP's solution is the right solution.  From the question, it seemed that you (might) want the most recent day for the "holidex", rather than getting no rows back if that is not the most recent day in the data.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough, but still appreciate you taking the time to look into this.